# C++ Scheduler for Arduino Uno

Tags: c++, arduino, task, scheduler, thread-priority

I would like to create/use a light homemade scheduler (in C++) for my program based on Arduino Uno (ATMega328P) : I want to manage my different "tasks" based on a priority task (according the execution time); have you got some examples about that ?

Thank you so much

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like one of [the following](http://playground.arduino.cc//Main/LibraryList#Sched) should fit your need. Or be a basis for expanding upon.